# how can i open eve-ng wizzard setup

Tags: linux, ubuntu, google-cloud-platform, debian

i try to install eve-ng with google cloud, i followed the steps from documentation. After i reboot linux machine, I open a terminal with ssh again and I can't see the setup from eve-ng it returns me to the linux machine.

```
5. Run The Installation Script
Once your VM is provisioned it will automatically be started. Use the built-in SSH feature to 
connect to the VM’s console.

Once you’re SSH’d into the VM become root, grab the installation script, update the package 
manager and upgrade current packages.

sudo -i
wget -O - http://www.eve-ng.net/repo/install-eve.sh | bash -i
apt update
apt upgrade
Reboot the VM.
```

HERE IS MY PROBLEM, at 6th step, this setup does not open, is there any command I can open it from cli? something like "open eve" or other ideas?
6. Run The Setup Wizard
Connect to it again via the built in SSH.
You will be presented with a configuration wizard.
STOP!
When you are greeted with the wizard to enter a root password, don’t!
Hold CTRL and press C, become root sudo -i
This will restart the wizard and allow you to change root’s password.
Follow the initial configuration wizard.
Enter Root Password:
Enter Root Password Again:
Hostname: anything you want (I leave default)
DNS Domain Name: anything you want (I leave default)
DHCP/Static IP: Choose DHCP/Static
NTP: (leave empty)
Proxy: Choose “Direct connection”
After hitting enter, the setup wizard will kick you out.

Answer (score 0):

What ubuntu version are you using?

EVE-NG Comminity is not running on version 18.04 or newer.